# redbean - strange error

Tags: php, redbean

I have the following code..

```
$support = R::load('nfcategory', 1);
$post = R::dispense('nfpost');
$post2 = R::dispense('nfpost');
$support->ownNfpost = array($post, $post2);
R::store($support);
```

And I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RedBean_Exception_Security' with message 'Cannot cast to bean.' in E:\wamp\www\neatforum2\neatforum\lib\rb.php on line 911
```

I've spent roughly an hour trying to fix this. Maybe it's because I'm tired... Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.